# Cohen's d for unequal variance

Tags: variance, effect-size, cohens-d

I know my two samples have unequal variance. Should I consider this in my calculation of the effect size? I'm using Cohen's d, which [Wikipedia](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjIpPOQqbHLAhWG1BoKHULzDzcQygQILTAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEffect_size%23Cohen.27s_d&usg=AFQjCNGR-_Gz1n2YXtclKXyFAqQlmbToxQ&sig2=_19AozwuBXQumt9sJTtcGw&bvm=bv.116274245,d.bGs&cad=rja) defines as

$d = \frac{\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2}{s}$

with

$s = \sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)s^2_1 + (n_2-1)s^2_2}{n_1+n_2 - 2}}$

However, I noticed that when performing the [t-test assuming *unequal* variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes.2C_unequal_variances), a different estimation of the variance is used (instead of the pooled variance). Should I adapt the Cohen's d formula as well?

Comment: very similar Q also unanswered: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210352/do-cohens-d-and-hedges-g-apply-to-the-welch-t-test#

Comment: See my answer to that question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/247011/1934

Answer (score 2):

When doing t tests, we divide the estimated mean difference with **standard error** \sqrt{Var}/\sqrt{N}. Whereas in Cohen's d, we divide the mean difference with pooled **standard deviation**. They are usually different.

Answer (score 1):

There's a recent article by Delacre et al recommending Hedge's g* based on the average SD of the two groups for unequal variance samples. You may check them out.

http://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2015/01/always-use-welchs-t-test-instead-of.html

https://psyarxiv.com/tu6mp/

Answer (score 0):

With unequal variances (where I find that $\frac{S^2_{bigger}}{S^2_{smaller}} \le 1.5$, this would be a moderate difference between variances according to Cohen, 1988) I give a range for d where I divide the difference of the means 1) by the bigger (lower bound for d) and 2) by the smaller (upper bound for d) standard deviation.

I should add that this strategy is purely descriptive and only serves the purpose of helping to interpret the size of the difference that may be there. As far as I know there is no statistical-mathematical argument for this strategy.
(I find it helpful though in cases where it seems plausible from a contextual perspective, say, the difference in well-being between control group and treatment group: even if you absolutely should interpret the differences in variability, one could say, that the relative difference between the means seems quite big, assuming the treatment could be modified in a way that it produces more similar outcomes, but moderate at best considering the seemingly very heterogeneous effects of the treatment.)