# Computing Cohen's D directly from a Welch's t statistic

Tags: t-test, meta-analysis, effect-size

I'm performing a meta-analysis and am trying to extract a Cohen's $\hat{d}$ effect size measure from a paper; however the paper does not report any means or SDs. They do, however, report the results of a welch's t-test. If this were a normal two-sample t-test I could directly compute the cohen's $\hat{d}$ as $\hat{d}$ = 2t /√(df), however, the denominator of Welch's t-statistic is different from the two-sample t-test denominator so this conversion won't work. Is there any way to compute the cohen's d in this context?  I've already looked at [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210352/do-cohens-d-and-hedges-g-apply-to-the-welch-t-test), but it did not appear to be relevant to my question

Edit 1: As pointed out by Glen_b I am looking for the estimate $\hat{d}$, not $d$. I updated accordingly

Edit 2: I know the degrees of freedom for the Welch's T-test, what I don't know are the means or SDs...

Comment: By Cohen's definition, $d$ is a population quantity ($\frac{|\mu_A-\mu_B|}{\sigma}$ in the two-tailed case, albeit his notation was slightly different). If you replace $\mu$s by $\bar{x}$s and $\sigma$ by a pooled sample standard deviation, it's an estimate of $d$. Conflating estimates with estimands is not a great idea. It can have some highly undesirable consequences (such as the connection between $d$ and power leading people to use $\hat{d}$ in a *post hoc* power calculation). It would be best to at least be clear that it's an estimate of $d$ rather than Cohen's actual $d$.

Comment: Note that what I call $\hat{d}$ above Cohen calls $d_s$, see p 66 of Cohen, J. (1988). *Statistical power analysis for the behavioral sciences*, 2e. Navarro (*Learning Statistics with R*) wisely uses $\delta$ for $d$ and $d$ for $\hat{d}$ ($d_s$), which follows the statistical conventions for population and sample quantities. (Ideally, then, $D$ would be the random variable whose realization is $d$.) It might have saved a lot of confusion in later readers if Cohen had similarly followed those conventions, as stating that $m$'s and $d$'s were population quantities didn't end up being sufficient

Comment: If you have Welch's t value and its two-sided P-value, you can back calculate the degrees-of-freedom using a simple iterative procedure in R - via the inverse cumulative Student's t distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first the case where the variances in the two groups are assumed to be homoscedastic. Then the true standardized mean difference is defined as $$\theta = \frac{\mu_1 - \mu_2}{\sigma},$$ where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the true means of the two groups and $\sigma$ the true standard deviation. We can estimate $\theta$ with $$d = \frac{\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2}{SD_p},$$ where $$SD_p = \sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)SD_1^2 + (n_2-1)SD_2^2}{n_1 + n_2 - 2}}$$ is the 'pooled' standard deviation, $\bar{x}_1$ and $\bar{x}_2$ are the observed means, $SD_1$ and $SD_2$ the standard deviations, and $n_1$ and $n_2$ the group sizes of the two groups. In principle, one could replace $SD_p$ with either $SD_1$ or $SD_2$, but this will yield a less efficient estimate of $\theta$. Also, since the test statistic for an independent samples t-test (Student's version) is $$t_s = \frac{d}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}}},$$ we can easily back-calculate $d$ with $$d = t_s \times \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}}.$$

If $n_1 = n_2$, then this simplifies to $d = \frac{2t_s}{\sqrt{N}}$, where $N$ is the total sample size (i.e., $N = n_1 + n_2$). While close, $d = \frac{2t_s}{\sqrt{df}}$ is not quite correct.

For Welsh's t-test, the test statistic is computed with $$t_w = \frac{\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{SD_1^2}{n_1} + \frac{SD_2^2}{n_2}}}.$$ It is not possible to back-calculate $d$ as defined above from knowing only this test statistic (and the group sizes), except in the case where $n_1 = n_2$, in which case $t_s = t_w$.

Comment: Great answer thanks! With respect to whether the conversion should be 
 2t /√(df) or  2t /√(n), I have seen some conflicting opinions. For example, the R package 'esc' puts sqrt(n) in the denominator (seemingly following this [paper](https://mason.gmu.edu/~dwilsonb/downloads/esformulas.pdf)) while the R package 'effectsize' [computes it with sqrt(df) in the denominator](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/effectsize/versions/0.8.3/topics/t_to_d).

Comment: If we define $d$ as shown above, then we can transform the test statistic from a Student's t-test to $d$ with $d = 2t / \sqrt{N}$ when $n_1 = n_2$ where $N = n_1 + n_2$. That's the math and not really a matter of opinion. In fact, using the degrees of freedom in place of $N$ in the denominator would inflate the already existing positive bias of $d$ (as an estimator of $\theta$) even further. Unless $N$ is really small though, the difference is negligible.

Comment: Yep that makes sense to me. I'll reach out to the maintainer of the effectsize package. In my field small N's are pretty common...